# How I can get a Substring from a String with haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have the next **text**:

```
blah blah blah with developmental venous anomaly (DVA)
```

as a `[String]` `[blah,blah,blah,with,developmental,venous,anomaly,(DVA)]`

where **`DVA`** is a the acronym from **`Developmental venous anomaly`** . I  know that the length of this acronym is 3, so the definition start 3 positions befores, and ends where is the acronym, `[developmental,venous,anomaly]`. I trying to implement a function for this. I know how do it with java, but I'm beginner in haskell and I can't do it.

Should be something like this:

```
f:: [String]->String-> [String]
```

where my inputs is `[blah,blah,blah,with,developmental,venous,anomaly,(DVA)] and  (DVA)`

and my output:  `[developmental,venous,anomaly]`

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. What is the input and the desired output of the function you're trying to write?

Comment: @ChrisMartin thank you so much for comment, the question was edited with my input and output

Comment: Should it also work with in put like "blah with developmental venous anomaly (DVA) blah blah", or with multiple (or zero) acronyms in a sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
desc a = reverse $ take ((length h)-2) xs           
    where (h:xs) = reverse $ words a                   


> desc "blah blah blah with developmental venous anomaly (DVA)"     
["developmental","venous","anomaly"]
```